# How can I add Keycloak security to messaging in Wildfly 10?

Tags: wildfly-10, keycloak, activemq-artemis

I tried to set the security domain of the messaging server to the Keycloak-enabled security domain, but the messaging subsystem (Apache activeMQ artemis) cannot find the keycloak classes.
How can I make the keycloak classes visible to the messaging system?

Comment: Can you add a stack-trace or any additional details about what exactly is failing in ActiveMQ Artemis?  Typically classloading issues in Wildfly are solved by modifying modules.  Have you modified the Artemis module to allow it to see the proper classes?